# Blackberry - background image/animation RIM OS 4.5.0

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, animation, rim-4.5

Please help me, how to set a background image for screen and How to do animations on any-field or  on text?

Thank You....

Comment: This really should be 2 separate questions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Background image

In Screen class there is a [protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#paintBackground(net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics)) method.
By some reason we can't use it directly to paint background image in screen. The catch:  paintBackground method is derived from Field class, and we can use it in VerticalFieldManager on example:

```
class BgScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {
 ButtonField mButton;
 public BgScreen(Bitmap background) {
  super();
  BGVerticalFieldManager manager = 
   new BGVerticalFieldManager(background);
  add(manager);
  mButton = new ButtonField("Button", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
  mButton.setChangeListener(this);
  manager.add(mButton);
 }

 public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
  if (mButton == field)
   Dialog.inform("You pressed button");
 }
}

class BGVerticalFieldManager extends VerticalFieldManager {
 Bitmap mBgBitmap = null;
 int mBgWidth = -1;
 int mBgHeight = -1;
 int mBgX = -1;
 int mBgY = -1;

 public BGVerticalFieldManager(Bitmap background) {
  super(USE_ALL_WIDTH | USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
  mBgBitmap = background;
  mBgWidth = mBgBitmap.getWidth();
  mBgHeight = mBgBitmap.getHeight();
  mBgX = (Display.getWidth() - mBgWidth) >> 1;
  mBgY = (Display.getHeight() - mBgHeight) >> 1;

 }

 protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {
  paintBackgroundBitmap(graphics);
  super.paintBackground(graphics);
 }

 private void paintBackgroundBitmap(Graphics graphics) {
  if (null != mBgBitmap) {
   graphics.drawBitmap(
    mBgX, mBgY, mBgWidth, mBgHeight, mBgBitmap, 0, 0);
  }
 }
}
```

### GIF animation

To use GIF animation, override [protected void paint(Graphics graphics)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#paint(net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics)) method and use [drawImage](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#drawImage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage,%20int,%20int,%20int)) of incremented frame index. Use [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) to invalidate field:

```
class GIFVerticalFieldManager extends VerticalFieldManager {
    EncodedImage mGIFImage = null;
    int mGIFWidth = -1;
    int mGIFHeight = -1;
    int mGIFX = -1;
    int mGIFY = -1;
    int mGIFFrameCount = -1;
    int mGIFFrameIndex = -1;
    final int mGIFDelay = 30;

    public GIFVerticalFieldManager(EncodedImage gifAnimation) {
        super(USE_ALL_WIDTH | USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
        mGIFImage = gifAnimation;
        mGIFWidth = mGIFImage.getWidth();
        mGIFHeight = mGIFImage.getHeight();
        mGIFX = (Display.getWidth() - mGIFWidth) >> 1;
        mGIFY = (Display.getHeight() - mGIFHeight) >> 1;
        mGIFFrameCount = mGIFImage.getFrameCount();
        mGIFFrameIndex = 0;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                invalidate();
            }
        }, mGIFDelay, mGIFDelay);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        paintGifAnimation(graphics);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

    private void paintGifAnimation(Graphics graphics) {
        if (null != mGIFImage) {
            graphics.drawImage(
                mGIFX, mGIFY, mGIFWidth, mGIFHeight, 
            mGIFImage, mGIFFrameIndex, 0, 0);
            mGIFFrameIndex++;
            if (mGIFFrameIndex > mGIFFrameCount - 1)
                mGIFFrameIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Great article - [Direct Screen Drawing](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/devjournals/resources/journals/jan_2006/direct_screen_drawing.jsp)

Comment: This is an excellent answer, I would recommend splitting this insto two separate questions to make it easier to find. Create a new question, cut the bottom half into that and edit the original question. Would do it myself, but I'm still a few hundred rep short.