# BlackBerry - draw image on the screen

Tags: user-interface, graphics, blackberry, java-me, png

How to draw png images with specific size and position on the screen?

Answer (score 27):

### Resize image

```
 public EncodedImage sizeImage(EncodedImage image, int width, 
  int height) {
  EncodedImage result = null;

  int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth());
  int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight());

  int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(width);
  int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(height);

  int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32,
    requiredWidthFixed32);
  int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32,
    requiredHeightFixed32);

  result = image.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);
  return result;
 }
```

This function will be used in the code below.

### Simply painting images

[Simply painting images http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9918/bb8310.png](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9918/bb8310.png)

Lets paint 9 images in a table way, images are different in size, but we will resize them to 80x80 and give them margins 10 px.

Assuming you have 9 png images in your project resources.

1. Load images
2. Resize images
3. Paint images on every paint event, within certain position

Code:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
 int mImgWidth = 80;
 int mImgHeight = 80;
 int mImgMargin = 10;
 String fileNames[] = { "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png",
   "6.png", "7.png", "8.png", "9.png" };
 EncodedImage[] mImages;

 public Scr() {
 super();
  prepareImages();
 }

 private void prepareImages() {
  mImages = new EncodedImage[fileNames.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
   EncodedImage image = EncodedImage
     .getEncodedImageResource(fileNames[i]);
   mImages[i] = sizeImage(image, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
  }
 }

 protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
  paintImages(graphics);
  super.paint(graphics);
 }

 private void paintImages(Graphics graphics) {
  int scrWidth = Display.getWidth();
  int columns = scrWidth / (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin);
  int rows = mImages.length / columns
    + (mImages.length % columns > 0 ? 1 : 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    int posX = j * (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;
    int posY = i * (mImgHeight + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;
    EncodedImage image = mImages[i * columns + j];
    graphics.drawImage(posX, posY, mImgWidth, mImgHeight,
      image, 0, 0, 0);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

### Simply painting images - optimization

Take a look at paint() method of Scr. On every refresh the whole table of images is repainting, that means 9 drawImage call on every paint. What if we just take a shapshot of this table and use it in paint() method?

```
class ScrOpt extends MainScreen {
 int mScrWidth = Display.getWidth();
 int mScrHeight = Display.getHeight();
 int mImgWidth = 80;
 int mImgHeight = 80;
 int mImgMargin = 10;
 String fileNames[] = { "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png",
   "6.png", "7.png", "8.png", "9.png" };
 EncodedImage[] mImages;
 Bitmap mImgTable;

 public ScrOpt() {
  super();
  prepareImages();
  mImgTable = paintImages();
 }

 private void prepareImages() {
  mImages = new EncodedImage[fileNames.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
   EncodedImage image = EncodedImage
     .getEncodedImageResource(fileNames[i]);
   mImages[i] = sizeImage(image, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
  }
 }

 private Bitmap paintImages() {
  Bitmap result = new Bitmap(mScrWidth, mScrHeight);
  Graphics graphics = new Graphics(result);
  int scrWidth = mScrWidth;
  int columns = scrWidth / (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin);
  int rows = mImages.length / columns
    + (mImages.length % columns > 0 ? 1 : 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    int posX = j * (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;
    int posY = i * (mImgHeight + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;
    EncodedImage image = mImages[i * columns + j];
    graphics.drawImage(posX, posY, mImgWidth, mImgHeight, image, 0,
      0, 0);
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {  
  super.paint(graphics);
  graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, mScrWidth, mScrHeight, mImgTable, 0, 0);
 }
}
```

You can otimize it even more, [using paintBackground() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365727/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-blackberry-jde-4-5-0-programming/1371657#1371657)

### Using BitmapField

All above is about painting images directly to screen using [Graphics](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html). Sometimes its great - when you want to display some animation or background image. But what if you want to keep standard UI user experience, and use images as a fields?

[alt text http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/7485/bb83102.png](http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/7485/bb83102.png)

The strait way is a [BitmapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html)

```
class ScrBmpField extends MainScreen {
 int mImgWidth = 80;
 int mImgHeight = 80;
 int mImgMargin = 10;
 String fileNames[] = { "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png",
   "6.png", "7.png", "8.png", "9.png" };
 BitmapField[] mBmpFields;

 public ScrBmpField() {
  super(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
  prepareBmpFields();  
 }

 private void prepareBmpFields() {
  mBmpFields = new BitmapField[fileNames.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
   EncodedImage image = EncodedImage
     .getEncodedImageResource(fileNames[i]);
   image = sizeImage(image, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
   mBmpFields[i] = 
       new BitmapField(image.getBitmap(), FOCUSABLE|FIELD_HCENTER);
   mBmpFields[i].setMargin(mImgMargin, mImgMargin, 
       mImgMargin, mImgMargin);
   add(mBmpFields[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

### Using BitmapField - custom layout

[alt text http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/403/bb83103.png](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/403/bb83103.png)

To set a custom positions of BitmapFields within manager, you can implement [manager with custom layout](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/javaknowledge/userInterface/kpa0203190635.shtml):

```
class ScrLayout extends MainScreen {
    int mScrWidth = Display.getWidth();
    int mScrHeight = Display.getHeight();
    int mImgWidth = 80;
    int mImgHeight = 80;
    int mImgMargin = 10;
    String fileNames[] = { "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png",
            "6.png", "7.png", "8.png", "9.png" };
    BitmapField[] mBmpFields;

    public ScrLayout() {
        super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
        prepareBmpFields();
    }

    private void prepareBmpFields() {
        LayoutManager manager = new LayoutManager();
        add(manager);
        mBmpFields = new BitmapField[fileNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
            EncodedImage image = EncodedImage
                    .getEncodedImageResource(fileNames[i]);
            image = sizeImage(image, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
            mBmpFields[i] = 
                new BitmapField(image.getBitmap(), FOCUSABLE);
            manager.add(mBmpFields[i]);
        }
    }

    class LayoutManager extends VerticalFieldManager {
        public LayoutManager() {
            super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
        }

        protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
            int columns = mScrWidth / (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin);
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < mBmpFields.length; i++) {
                int posX = j * (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;
                int posY = i * (mImgHeight + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;
                Field field = mBmpFields[i];
                layoutChild(field, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
                setPositionChild(field, posX, posY);

                j = (j == columns - 1) ? 0 : j + 1;
            }
            setExtent(mScrWidth, mScrHeight);
        }
        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            return mScrWidth;
        }
        public int getPreferredHeight() {
            return mScrHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere in an initialization function:

```
 Image myImage = Image.createImage("/myimage.png");
```

And in the paint function of your canvas:

```
 g.drawImage(myImage, posX, posY, Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
```

(where g is the Graphics object you get from the paint function)

edit: fixed small error as pointed out in comments

Answer (score 2):

If you use net.rim.device.api.system.PNGEncodedImage or one of the other classes extended from net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage you can use the scaleImage32(int scaleX, int scaleY) method (available in OS 4.2 and latter) to scale the image to the size you want. Be aware though that scaleX and scaleY, though typed as int are actually net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32 so to display the image at one half size:

```
EncodedImage halfSize = myImage.scaleImage32(Fixed32.toFP(2), Fixed32.toFP(2));
```

Or for an image twice original size:

```
EncodedImage twiceSize = myImage.scaleImage32(Fixed32.tenThouToFP(5000), Fixed32.tenThouToFP(5000));
```

Comment: only drawback is that the code uses rim only classes and is therefore not portable to any other java device.

Comment: True, but your answer only fulfills one of the two requirements specified by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
private VerticalFieldManager mainBackVerticalFieldManager = null;

int deviceWidth = Display.getWidth();
int deviceHeight = Display.getHeight();    

mainBackVerticalFieldManager   = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL|VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR){
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, deviceWidth,deviceHeight,Bitmap.getBitmapResource(Constants.PURCHASE_SUMMARY_BG), 0,0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        };
    };
```

Here you can change deviceWidth and height as your requirement.