# Developing photo gallery application

Tags: blackberry, java-me, startup

I want to develop a photo gallery in Blackberry.
Please give any suggestions about functionality and implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple things to do:

- gallery layout variations (table, list, tape)
- several thumbnail size variations
- info from file (format, resolution, size, etc)
- file browser component
- send mail/publish web etc
- camera integration

Additional features:

- slide show
- rating functionality
- converter functionality
- synchronization device-device, device-desktop, device-web
- home screen wallpaper ([available up from 4.7](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/homescreen/HomeScreen.html#setBackgroundImage(java.lang.String)))

See for code samples:
[BlackBerry Dev Blog - How to use Table View layout](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Developer-s-Blog/How-to-use-Table-View-layout/ba-p/356886)
[StackOverflow - BlackBerry - draw image on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426299/blackberry-draw-image-on-the-screen)