# A splash screen which doesnot just disappear but fades in/out

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, splash-screen

I have a splash screen which appears for a few seconds before the application home screen is loaded. And then the home screen is pushed in. 
But I need to fade out the splash screen before the home screen appears.
Any idea how to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you should do two things:

1. push application home screen, and after that push splash screen

   - inside splash screen before close start png "animation" with growing transparency (image should be size of screen)

See also
[Blackberry - background image/animation RIM OS 4.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365727/blackberry-background-image-animation-rim-os-4-5-0)

Comment: Ok. There is a method setGlobalAlpha for transparency.Thanks