# How to flip a UI component when doing BlackBerry Java development?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I'm looking into porting my iPhone application to the BlackBerry and have run into a wall with the out of the box UI components and UI animations available for the BlackBerry. One feature that I really, really need to figure out is how do I flip over a UI component on the BlackBerry. For example, lets say that I have a UI component for a playing card. When the user selects that card I would like to flip it over to reveal what's on the other side.

Also, can anyone point me to any resources (books, websites, etc.) that deal with animation on BlackBerry devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive effect in two ways:

- BitmapField **layout animation** with image switch in the middle
- BitmapField (or any custom field with image) **image animation** with image switch in the middle

See animation related articles:
[BB KB - How To Display an animated GIF](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Display_an_animated_GIF.html?nodeid=1405903&vernum=0)
[The BlackBerry Graphical User Interface: Part 2 - Direct Screen Drawing](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/devjournals/resources/journals/jan_2006/direct_screen_drawing.jsp)
[SO - Blackberry - fields layout animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497073/blackberry-fields-layout-animation)
[SO - Blackberry - background image/animation RIM OS 4.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365727/blackberry-background-image-animation-rim-os-4-5-0)