# Sprite support on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, animation, java-me, sprite

I am creating a game using the BlackBerry Java API. I want to show an animation -- can I use the sprite class? Is there any similar functionality avaliable in the Blackberry Java API?

Answer (score 3):

See guidelines [Blackberry Java SDK - Game development](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21158/BlackBerry_Java_SDK-Development_Guide--1295241-0927034411-001-6.0-US.pdf), starting from RIM API 6.0 there is a [net.rim.device.api.animation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/animation/package-summary.html#package_description) package.

And for previous versions see [Blackberry - background image/animation RIM OS 4.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365727/blackberry-background-image-animation-rim-os-4-5-0)